# How to make 'git log --oneline' show which commit messages are multiline

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

I find myself doing `git log --oneline` quite often to get a quick glance at changes I am about to push *to* or merge *from* the remote. Is it possible to append some identifier (such as "[...]") to mark that commit message as a multiline one, so I can know that there is more information there?

Basically, what I want is this:

```
e1140de Some commit message
d1f58d1 Some multine commit message [...]
736f778 Some other commit message
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632172/367456), I came up with an alternative to my requirement:

```
git log --format="%h %s%n%b"
```

This is just like `--oneline`, except it puts a linebreak and the message body just after the message subject. It looks much better with some coloring:

```
git log --format="%C(yellow)%h%Creset %Cgreen%s%Creset%n%b"
```

Comment: We have multiline comments by default in commit history. How do I get the last line of multiline commit?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with some scripting. There is a message body token for the format in git log (`%b`).

But nothing can do that in one command: You have to see whether the message body is empty or not.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the token for the message body. For the record, it is `%b`

Comment: Adding that to the answer :) you don't get blank lines? No scripting needed then :)

Answer (score 1):

I got used to manually append "(s.b.)" for this which stands for "see below".

You may use a prepare-commit-msg hook to append it automatically if a commit msg is multiline.

Comment: I do not really want to mess with the commit messages, it is just a visualization requirement.